# How to access the data after post in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

My Viewer

```
<button type="submit" ng:click="sendviewer(vl.viewerid)" ></button>
```

My Controller

```
$scope.viewerDetails = [];
var viewerid = [];

$scope.sendviewer = function(viewer){
    var success = function(data)
    {
        for( var i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
        {
            var obj = data[i];
            if(obj.viewerid != undefined) {
                viewerid.push(obj.viewerid);
            }
        }
        $scope.viewerDetails = viewerid;
    }

    viewerService.postViewer(viewer).success(success);
}
```

My Service

```
return {
    postViewer: function(viewer){
        $location.path('/viewerdetails');
        return $http({ 
            method: 'POST', 
            url: 'api.php', 
            data: { 
                'view': viewer 
            },
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
        });
    }
}
```

My returned data is available in function memory but how will i be able to access that data outside the function to be accessible inside my view? if i try to do {{ viewerDetails.viewerid }} will display blank.

Comment: you set `$scope.viewerDetails` to be an array. the variable `viewerid` is an array which you set to `$scope.viewerDetails`. This array doesn't have a `viewerid` property, and that's why you don't see it.

Comment: if i do console.log($scope.viewerDetails) right there after retrieving the data it shows correct "1" but when i do console.log($scope.viewerDetails) right outside the function returns empty

Comment: not sure which function you're talking about, but this could be becuase it's an asynchronous call, and "outside" the function is before the callback is executed. And also, if `$scope.viewerDetails` is a "1" why are you trying to get `{{viewerDetails.viewerid}}`, maybe you should just do `{{viewerDetails}}`?

Comment: By outside the function i mean after i submit the data it should print the returned data from $scope.sendviewer(viewer) but instead returns empty i tried with only {{ viewerDetails }} only but returns [] (empty) i made a screenshot here with the returned data inside the call and when i try to use it http://prntscr.com/9f76sg

Comment: well, if that is a screen shot of your console.logs you clearly see that the last console.log is from the callback function. of course the first ones doesn't have any data until the success function has been executed. Try do a `$scope.$apply()` after you do: `$scope.viewerDetails = viewerid;` and just using `{{viewerDetails}}` in the html

Comment: I have tried and i receive that $digest is already in progress.

Comment: if, in your success-callback, the variable-array `viewerid` is console logged as `["1"]`, and you assign it to `$scope.viewerDetaills`. Then `{{viewerDetails}}` in the html should show `["1"]`. If not there is probably some detail you're omitting, or some other typo, because this should be fine

Comment: Is there any other way to accomplish my code? It should take the vl.viewerid to post it to PHP and return the data to make it available to fill the table information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like the for-loop is just unnecessary, kind of weird actually.

```
$scope.viewerIds = [];

$scope.sendviewer = function(viewer){
    var success = function(data)
    {
        var obj = data[0];
        if(obj.viewerid != undefined) {
           $scope.viewerIds.push(obj.viewerid);
        }
    }

    viewerService.postViewer(viewer).then(success);
}
```

also you should not use `success` since it is deprecated. Use promise syntax with `then` instead.
This would add the id of the result of the call to the $scope.viewerIds array.
It is not entierly clear if this is what you want. but to me it looks like it.

Are you sure the `data` is like you expect it? an array where the first element is your object. This is also kind of weird api to be honest..

and then in your html you could perhaps loop the array to show the ids:

```
<div ng-repeat="id in viewerIds"> ID: {{id}}</div>
```

Comment: I tried this way too but it seem to return still the data inside the success but when passed to the viewer is still empty. i have no idea why it won't display. Could be because is available only within the $scope.sendviewer = function(viewer) button is called? do i need to do like sendviewer().viewerDetails to make it accessible or something? Regards

Comment: well, You never showed where you got `vl.viewerId`, so I'm not sure what data this contains, but I was under the impression that the Post call was actually successful and you got some result back. You are aware that the success-function is called once you get the response from the Post-call?

Comment: Well the vl.viewers is an array of ID's when i click in one ID i give that ID to he sendviewers (viewer) then i make the post, it returns the data you can see here http://prntscr.com/9f8yq7 but is available just in that console.log($scope.viewerDetails) which i put inside the var success, but i can't output it to the viewer it always say is empty

Comment: I don't quite understand. If `$scope.viewerDetails` has the correct data, but you can't view it in the html? How are you using it in the html.

Comment: First i have this button http://prntscr.com/9f95vu which submits the post to the service my controller looks like this http://prntscr.com/9f96l5 then on my viewer http://prntscr.com/9f95i1 i've added that $scope.values just for test

Comment: Why the `$location.path`? This might make your controller re-run and the `$scope.viewerDetails` will be reset to empty array. I don't really think there is anything wrong with the code you posted in your answer, but I get the feeling it's something else in you application structure maybe..

Comment: the $location.path is because it takes the result to a new page where need to display the data for that viewer. As you can see the console.log($scope.values) is after it reloads the page and i have the data in the console.log so the data is still there after relog, it just don't want to let me use it. I hope i haven't used too much of your time, i will set it as answered however and i will search maybe a different approach to make it work or something. Thank you.

Comment: try and read up on how to do asynchronous programming with angular and javascript. Maybe consider to the $location.path inside the success-function. Good Luck!

Comment: I have fixed it by adding the controller right on the body and now works fine

Answer (score 0):

Since `viewerid` is a local array variable, the data stored inside it is not available outside the scope. You should store `viewerid` inside `$scope`. Like

```
$scope.viewerid = [];
```

Now it can be accessed on the DOM.

Comment: I will test this now and come back with a result